# MikTex update - What does the "to be repaired" message mean?

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

Today, I wanted to udpate my MiKTeX install, but among `required` and `optional` update informations for my packages, I also got a `to be repaired` message, see below

> [image]

I thought this would be mentioned in the [MiKTeX manual](https://miktex.org/docs), but I could not find details on this.

Looking at other posts, a "repair" seems to mean an update of the fndb or package maps, but I am flying in the blind here. I do not think I stopped a previous package install or update, which could lead to a need for repair of some sort.

Can anyone clarify the meaning of this message or link to a relevant document ?